# how can i put user input in a array in julia

Tags: julia

I would like to collect user input (a list of number separated by a space) split it in to an array and transform the data in it from string to float.
**Basically i want to recreate this python code in Julia**:

```
userlist = input('[+]type in a list of number separated by a space: ').split()
for i in range(len(userlist)): userlist[i] = float(userlist[i])
```

i tried this but didn't work:

```
print("type in a list of number separated by a space: ")
userinput = readline()
userlist = rsplit(userinput, " ")
for i in 0:length(userlist)
  userlist[i] = userlist[i]::Float64
end
```

Comment: In addition to the other issues, note that Julia `Array`s use 1-based indexing and inclusive ranges, so `0:length(userlist)` should be `1:length(userlist)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You're close. You parse a `String` into `Float64` with `parse`, not a type assertion.

```
userlist[i] = parse(Float64, userlist[i])
```

This still won't quite work, since `userlist` is an array of strings and can't store floats (arrays in Julia are stored with their type by default, for efficiency). You could make a new array and then do the `for` loop like you have been, but you can also just use `map`.

```
userlist = map(x -> parse(Float64, x), userlist)
```

Comment: For the sake of type stability `const usernumbers = map(x -> parse(Float64, x), userlist)` would be a good choice.

Comment: first off, are you italian? btw i check the type of userlist and it's a vector so can't use the first option but the second one seems to work

Comment: I'm glad to hear it works for you. And yes, I am Italian by heritage, though I'm USA-born. :)

Comment: im 100% italian, finally some italians on this platform

Comment: [ot] Italian too :-)) But I have to say we are really rare in the Julia world :-) :-) [/ot]

Comment: Or use broadcasting: userlist = parse.(Float64, userlist)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `using DelimitedFiles` as it is usually more robust (you always end up with user inputting some wrong data etc.:

```
readdlm(IOBuffer(readline()))
```

For an example:

```
julia> readdlm(IOBuffer(readline()))
1 2 3
1×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  2.0  3.0
```